# extract elements from a pointer to pointer to array of structures

Tags: c++, pointers, struct

I have a problem with a point to a pointer to an array of structures.

I declare and initialize three points to structure which has a member `val`. 
I create a pointer `arr` to an array of pointer to structure. 
Then I create a pointer `pa` to pointer `arr` and a pointer `pa1` to `pa`.

I encounter the problem when I try to extract the second element of the `arr` using `pa1`.

Main.cpp

```
#include<iostream> 
#include<cstdio> 

struct a{ 
    int val; 
}; 

int main(){ 

    // create structures 
    a *a1 = new a; 
    a1->val = 5; 
    a *a2 = new a; 
    a2->val = 3; 
    a *a3 = new a; 
    a3->val = 4; 

    a *arr[3] = { a1, a2, a3 }; 
    a **pa = arr; 

    std::cout << "Using pa:\n"; 
    std::printf( "1st val: %d\n", (*(pa+0))->val ); 
    std::printf( "1st pos: %p\n", (*(pa+0)) ); 
    std::printf( "2nd val: %d\n", (*(pa+1))->val ); 
    std::printf( "2nd pos: %p\n", (*(pa)+1) ); // modified 

    std::cout << std::endl << std::endl; 

    // a pointer to pa's value
    a *pa1 = *pa;  

    std::cout << "Using pa1:\n"; 
    std::printf( "1st val: %d\n", pa1->val ); 
    std::printf( "1st pos: %p\n", pa1 ); 
    std::printf( "2nd val: %d\n", (pa1+1)->val ); 
    std::printf( "2nd pos: %p\n", pa1+1 ); 


    delete a1, a2, a3;  

    return 0; 
}
```

Then I get the result as below,

```
Using pa:
1st val: 5
1st pos: 0000000000e761e0
2nd val: 3
2nd pos: 0000000000e761e4

Using pa1:
1st val: 5
1st pos: 0000000000e761e0
2nd val: 0
2nd pos: 0000000000e761e4
```

The question is why the `2nd val` of `pa1` is not **3** but **0**?

Both `pa` and `pa1` seem to point to the same address `0000000000e761e4`.

**UPDATE**

The line `// modified` should be `std::printf( "2nd pos: %p\n", *(pa+1) );`.

And the result becomes as below

```
Using pa:
1st val: 5
1st pos: 0000000000ee61d0
2nd val: 3
2nd pos: 0000000000ee61f0


Using pa1:
1st val: 5
1st pos: 0000000000ee61d0
2nd val: 0
2nd pos: 0000000000ee61d4
```

The `2nd pos` of `pa` and `pa1` is actually not the same.

Now the question is **How can I get the second element from `arr` using `pa1`?**

Comment: I don't think you can `delete pa1;` and others, for that matter.

Comment: `pa1+1` is `(*pa)+1`. Why do you expect this to be the same as `*(pa+1)`?

Comment: The line that is confusing you is  std::printf( "2nd pos: %p\n", ((*pa)+1) );
this should be std::printf( "2nd pos: %p\n", (*(pa+1)) ); to match what you have on the line above. This will show that they aren't pointing to the same address.

Comment: @SouravGhosh none of those deletes are valid (maybe pa1 deletes a1). All of them tries to delete stack variable `arr`. And allocated `a1`..`a3` persists.

Comment: @CraigR Thx. I have update the my question.

Comment: @SouravGhosh and @KIIV, you're right. Only dynamic allocation variable with ```new``` need to ```delete```.  @Melebius I have modified the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make a diagram, what is stored where and how:

For example:

```
// Allocated values (they are completely unrelated and may point into different locations):
a1 = 0x11111100;
a2 = 0x22222200;
a3 = 0x33333300;
// Where each of those addresses points to the place in memory with one constructed element of a 

// next is creating arr of three pointers to a:
a * arr[3] = { a1, a2, a3 };
// which is effectively:
a * arr[3] = { 0x11111100, 0x22222200, 0x33333300};

// the arr is stored somewhere too, and it contains location, where those three addresses are stored
arr = 0xFFFFF340; // for example

// so when you do:
a ** pa = arr;
// then
pa == 0xFFFFF340;
// and pa + 1 == 0xFFFFF344  (increment depends on architecture) 
// ==> dereferenced value is location where pointer to a2 is stored
```

However, if you do:

```
a * pa1 = *pa; 
// then it means you did:
a * pa1 = arr[0];
// therefore:
pa1 == 0x11111100;
// and pa1+1 is memory location after a1 object eg.:
pa1+1 == 0x11111104;
// but as you've created only one element in that place, dereferencing it causes buffer overflow and using uninitialized memory
```

BTW: you could use debugger and variable watches to track what is happening and what is pointing where and its values

EDIT: Added bigger structs, so differences are much more obvious:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct Data {
    int x[100] = {0};
};


int main()
{
    Data * a = new Data[10];
    Data * b = new Data[5];
    Data * c = new Data[1];

    printf("a value: %p\n", a);
    printf("b value: %p\n", b);
    printf("c value: %p\n", c);

    Data * arr[] = { a, b, c};

    for (auto const& ptr : arr)
    {
        printf("Arr: element addr: %p  position: %ld  ptr to: %p\n", &ptr, &ptr-arr, ptr);
    }

    Data ** pa = arr;
    printf("pa   value: %p  dereferenced value: %p\n", pa, *pa);
    printf("pa+1 value: %p  dereferenced value: %p\n", pa+1, *(pa+1));
    printf("pa+2 value: %p  dereferenced value: %p\n", pa+2, *(pa+2));

    Data * pa0 = *pa;
    printf("pa0   value: %p\n", pa0);
    printf("pa0+1 value: %p\n", pa0+1);
    printf("pa0+2 value: %p\n", pa0+2);

    // cleanup - eventually :D  But using std::unique_ptr would be much better.
}
```

And the output:

```
a value: 0x55bd5d988eb0
b value: 0x55bd5d989e60
c value: 0x55bd5d98a640
Arr: element addr: 0x7ffc528dcf00  position: 0  ptr to: 0x55bd5d988eb0
Arr: element addr: 0x7ffc528dcf08  position: 1  ptr to: 0x55bd5d989e60
Arr: element addr: 0x7ffc528dcf10  position: 2  ptr to: 0x55bd5d98a640
pa   value: 0x7ffc528dcf00  dereferenced value: 0x55bd5d988eb0
pa+1 value: 0x7ffc528dcf08  dereferenced value: 0x55bd5d989e60
pa+2 value: 0x7ffc528dcf10  dereferenced value: 0x55bd5d98a640
pa0   value: 0x55bd5d988eb0
pa0+1 value: 0x55bd5d989040
pa0+2 value: 0x55bd5d9891d0
```

Comment: The ```a *pa1 = *pa;``` exactly points to the *content* that the ```pa``` points to, which is the ```a1```. So when I execute ```pa+1```, it is exactly moving only the size of ```struct a``` . Am I right?

Comment: Another question is **Why the ```pa+1``` moves 32 bytes not 8 bytes?** The size of pointer is 8 bytes.

Comment: @wukaihua119 yes, it should be moving to the next (but not allocated) object. Another issue: `std::printf( "2nd pos: %p\n", *(pa+1)` you are not printing `pa+1`, you are printing address at that location.  You should make some allocations between a1 .. a3 allocations so it's not stored in consecutive memory and it's more obvious to spot

Comment: @wukaihua119 I've added more obvious example with output (-std=c++11 or you can unroll that loop)

Comment: Oh, I mess up. The ```pa+1``` is exactly the address of the second element of the ```arr```. ```*(pa+1)``` is the address of  ```a2```.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think I solve my questions.

Answer (score 0):

Both `pa` and `pa1` seem to point to the same address `0000000000e761e4`.

*But* they are of different type. Therefor the `+1` gives a different address.

`pa1` is of type `a*`, therefor the `pa1+1` is `reinterpret_cast<a*>(reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(pa1)+sizeof(a))`. Note we stripped one layer of indirection for calculating the offset.

`pa` is of type `a**`, therefor the `pa1+1` is `reinterpret_cast<a**>(reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(pa)+sizeof(a*))`.

Since `reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(pa)==reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(pa1)`, but `sizeof(a)!=sizeof(a*)` we have different results.

The thing is that `pa1` is not the first address in an array of `a`! Therefor this calculation is wrong.

Comment: @Scheff I messed up. Could you have read on the second version?